# Moto G2 Marshmallow thowing exception on converting date format

Tags: simpledateformat, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am applying simple date format to my date string. The coversion is working fine in lollipop and marshmallow version of Moto G3 but it is throwing parceable exception in Moto G2.

Here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt;

        if(dateString.contains(":"))
        {
            fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
        }
        else
           fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh a");

        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = fmt.parse(dateString);
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        return fmtOut.format(date);
```

Log Cat:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "11 AM" (at offset 3)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:579)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/ccom.example.k  W/System.err:     at com.braintech.kwikgrocery.utils.Utility.convertTimeFormat(Utility.java:236)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k  W/System.err:     at com.braintech.kwikgrocery.activity.CheckOutConfirmOrderActivity$GetTimeSlots.doInBackground(CheckOutConfirmOrderActivity.java:289)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k  W/System.err:     at com.braintech.kwikgrocery.activity.CheckOutConfirmOrderActivity$GetTimeSlots.doInBackground(CheckOutConfirmOrderActivity.java:239)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k  W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k  W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k  W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k  W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
02-18 13:48:21.886 1562-2096/com.example.k  W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call trim on the string and Replace

```
 SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

With

```
 SimpleDateFormat fmtOut = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
```